# Why I can't reference to another script eve if I made the variable of the other script public?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to reference the Scaling script into the ObjectsManipulation script so I can use the Scaling methods and properties.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectsManipulation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Scaling scaling;
```

And the Scaling script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Scaling : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToScale;
    public float duration = 1f;
    public Vector3 minSize;
    public Vector3 maxSize;
    public bool scaleUp = false;
    public Coroutine scaleCoroutine;

    public void Inits()
    {
     objectToScale.transform.localScale = minSize;
    }

    public IEnumerator scaleOverTime(GameObject targetObj, Vector3 toScale, float duration)
    {
        float counter = 0;
        Vector3 startScaleSize = targetObj.transform.localScale;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, counter / duration);
            if (scaleUp)
            {
                var lookPos = transform.position - objectToScale.transform.position;
                lookPos.y = 0;
                var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
                objectToScale.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(objectToScale.transform.rotation, rotation, counter / duration);
            }
            else
            {
                var lookPos = transform.position - objectToScale.transform.position;
                lookPos.y = 0;
                var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Camera.main.transform.forward);
                objectToScale.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(objectToScale.transform.rotation, rotation, counter / duration);
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The script ObjectsManipulation is attached to a GameObject.
But in the editor in the Inspector of ObjectsManipulation I can't add the Scaling script tried to drag Scaling to it but can't.

Comment: Scaling has no properties, only fields. I don't know if that is a problem for Unity but most things require properties.

Comment: You have been a member of StackOverflow for 40 days, and you have already asked 36 questions. Don't you think you could have found an answer on your own? (Like this one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `Scaling` currently extends `MonoBehaviour` which requires that it be attached to a GameObject.

You can't directly drag the *script* to the inspector field because the field is for an *instance* of that class, not for a reference to *the class itself.*

You either need to:

1. Remove the `: MonoBehaviour` from the Scaling class so that it is not a Component, then call `new Scaling()` inside `ObjectsManipulation` somewhere, assigning it to the field.
2. Attache the `Scaling` script to a GameObject and use `GetComponent<Scaling>()` to assign a reference to the field.